# How to estimate relative risk for a small group which has 0 members with the outcome?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a contingency table that looks like this:

```
                Disease          Not Disease
Exposed           372              870
Not Exposed         0               23
```

What methods would I use to estimate if there is a statistically significant difference between the exposed and not exposed?

Comment: Fisher's exact test may work.

Comment: @Tim let's say that the outcome is having any allergy and the exposure is having ever lived in a house with a microwave.

Comment: @Tim There can be--and often is--baseline risk. For instance, about a third of US adults will eventually die of cancer. Exposure to a carcinogen, then, potentially will increase the risk, but lack of *that particular exposure* is not going to eliminate all risk of dying from cancer!  In many experiments, things happen to the control subjects: that's why we have controls in the first place. This particular table is extraordinary in *not* exhibiting any occurrences of the disease among the 23 unexposed individuals.

Answer (score 0):

Expected:-

```
                Disease          Not Disease
Exposed           365.24           876.76
Not Exposed         6.76            16.24
```

as expected cell values is big enough you can test by Chi-square contingency test.

Comment: (-1) *What* are those numbers? *How* were they calculated? Sorry, but your answer does *not* provide enough information to understand what do you mean.

Comment: these are expected outcomes $\frac{(sum~of~data~in~that~row)(sum~of~data~in~that~column)}{sum~of~total~data}$

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149219/what-is-the-definition-of-expected-counts-in-chi-square-tests/149223#149223

Comment: But this should be a part of your answer if you refer to $\chi^2$.